# How to open html link in a new window instead of a new tab on Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: html

My links correctly open a new window when using IE8; but when I use Firefox or Chrome, they just open a new tab.

I am using the code `target="_blank"` for my links.

How do I fix this so it opens a new browser window and not just another tab?

This fix needs to be for everyone that views the page and not just for my personal use.

Comment: The browsers let the user define whether `target="_blank"` opens a new window or tab. It's best not to try and override the user's preferrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there with the browser, because they supports tabbing, it will open in a tab. Having said that, there are probably some settings for them in each browser as well as addons that control that, for example, in firefox, you can control window positioning, tabs and a lot more with Tab Mix Plus addon.

Note that you can also open in new window with `window.open` eg:

```
window.open('example.html', 'name', 'settings')
```

Comment: yes we use a javascript to open it. 
  <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="window.open('http://www.something.com/somwehere', 'NewButtonWindowName','width=1000,height=800,scrollbars=yes')">